# Sci-fi young teen novel about a boy who is abducted by aliens and returned 2 years later?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, alien-abduction, time-dilation

I recall a short novel that is the story of a 12 year old boy who encounters some type of extra-terrestrial entity from a lake. He is deposited 2 years later (at age 14) and sees how much his life has changed. A girl he knew sports a perm and a bra and is dating his friend and they even go on a date (with parental supervision.) I can't remember for sure, but I think the alien manifests as a glowing head from the lake, and I am not sure if he was abducted and everybody noticed his 24 month disappearance (but I'm leaning more towards it) or if 2 years time has passed for the Earth but not for him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Door in the Lake](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/638526.The_Door_in_the_Lake) by Nancy Butts.

[image: The Door in the Lake]
[image: The Door in the Lake]

> After vanishing without a trace one night during a camping trip, twelve-year-old Joey reappears two years later, showing no signs of having aged and carrying memories of a strange light in the sky.

I used [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=alien%20lake%20young%20adult%20site%3Agoodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F) and it was top of the list!